# Document opening from application page in SharePoint 2013 Enterprise - Chrome situation

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-2013

I'm working on a system based on on-premise SharePoint 2013 (Enterprise). I'm using quite a few application pages and one of such pages has a link to a file (.docx to be precise). The file is located in a specific SharePoint library so I'm using SharePoint:ListViewByQuery to obtain it.
The issue is, in Chrome, the document gets downloaded instead of opened for editing when opened from the application page. IE works fine (document opens for editing).

This is not an overall SharePoint issue - opening a file directly from the document library opens it correctly for editing. So my question is, how to achieve the same behavior on an application page?